# LLDB stack trace only shows last 2 calls in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

Currently having trouble debugging with XCode. All stack traces only show last two calls made. Can't use `lldb` console too. For example a simple `unrecognized selector` error only shows this trace log

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x32d2e960 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x32d2e960 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x37c4ae06 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 170
```

Comment: I have the same problem... I'm using mac os X 10.7 and i already did mdimport . in all the symbols folders. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try printing `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` from the debugger, which sometimes works when the debugger doesn't. It doesn't really surprise me that

Additionally, my experience is that GDB is far more reliable.

Comment: gdb (and `callStackSymbols`) do a straight stack walk.  lldb inspects the instruction of the method to determine how registers are saved and the stack is manipulated.  The lldb stackwalk on arm has been improved over the last year but the Obj-C hand-optimized dispatch routines are very hard to analyze correctly staticly.  The simple follow-the-frame-chain algorithm used by gdb and `callStackSymbols` will also fail in other cases, neither of these will work correctly all of the time.  Stack unwinding can be pretty tricky.

Comment: @JasonMolenda I'm pretty sure that GDB does not do a naive stack walk — often it fails to give a backtrace where `+callStackSymbols` works.

Comment: Nice trick. Thanks! Wish there was a less bothersome fix though. :(

Answer (score 5):

A simple XCode restart solved the problem. But this bug keep happening after a while later. I'll report a bug about this.

Comment: Simple but effective. Thank you! I had the same problem. The debugger would only show the last two stack trace elements. The invocations were all plain simple static method calls. A restart of xcode solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Unwinding through the Objective-C runtime functions can be tricky on arm, the assembly is hand-tuned and lldb can have trouble figuring out how to unwind past them. In this case it looks like it got one frame farther and then couldn't get any farther.